# Need help for extracting columnar data

Tags: python

I wrote the code as below its extracting all tabular data by splitting. Now i want to
extract the last column(Values) data by removing Text in the middle of the table.

```
    import re
    f_read = open('filename','r')
    f_write=open('filename','w')
    str='CEN/4'
    for line in f_read:    
        m=re.search(str,line)
        if m:
           for line in f_read:      # loop over the rows
                if not line.strip():
                  continue
           line = line.split(' ',1)   # parse the columns
           print line
           f_write.writelines(line)
```

Table looks like this followed by values in each column.Now i want to remove the text and extract the values.

```
        S T R E S S E S   I N   Q U A D R I L A T E R A L   E L E M E N T S   ( Q U A D 4 )        OPTION = BILIN  

ELEMENT              FIBER            STRESSES IN ELEMENT COORD SYSTEM         PRINCIPAL STRESSES (ZERO SHEAR)               
  ID      GRID-ID   DISTANCE        NORMAL-X      NORMAL-Y      SHEAR-XY      ANGLE        MAJOR         MINOR       VON MISES 

  121      3423      342             4545          45435        4345           42353     3456456       67658          3435
```

Comment: So you just want to turn the last row of that table into a list of integers?

Comment: Why are you searching for `'CEN/4'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question, there's several things wrong with your code. Notably, you can't read and write to same file in the manner shown. To complicate the situation, there are nested`for`loops, both reading lines from the same input file.

Here's a revised version that avoids those problems by writing to a separate output file and doing everything under the control of single `for` loop. I also duplicated the line of data in the input file and changed all the numbers on it so they start with a `9` so there would be more than one line of data for testing purposes.

```
import re

with open('filename','r') as f_read, open('filename2','w') as f_write:
    for line in (line.strip() for line in f_read):
        if re.search(r'^\d+', line):  # line starts with a number?
            columnar_data = ' '.join(line.split())
            print columnar_data
            f_write.write(columnar_data+'\n')
```

Contents of output file (`filename2`):

```
121 3423 342 4545 45435 4345 42353 3456456 67658 3435
921 9423 942 9545 95435 9345 92353 9456456 97658 9435
```

Comment: its actually working fine but the above table starts from the middle of the text file so what i did is to search for a string and from that it has to start.it is reading the whole file from searched string to end of the file.Now i want to stop at certain point which doesn't have the string character.And i want to extract the last column data.

Comment: What certain point do you want to stop at? When you reach it, stop writing out data until you've read the last line, when that happens write the last line read (which until now you had been ignoring since you reached the certain point) and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell what you are trying to do. But if all you want to do is read in the data from the last line of that file, you can do something like this:

```
def read_last_line(file_path):
    f = open(file_path, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    last_line = lines[-1].split()
    return last_line
```

Notice that `lines[-1]` is a quick way to get the last element in an array. In this case, that array is an array where each element is a line in your file. I think this may be the important trick you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think it is likely that in the real case there are many lines containing values (one for each of many element IDs). To output all the values only, I'd suggest something like:

```
import re
f_read = open('quad4.txt','r')
f_write=open('quad4.out','w')
str = 'GRID-ID'
for line in f_read: 
    m=re.search(str,line)
    if m:
        break

for line in f_read:   # loop over the rows
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        vallist = line.split()   # parse the columns
        print (vallist)
        f_write.write("%s\n" % "\t".join(vallist)
```

This reads the file until it finds a line containing "GRID-ID" then it starts splitting any non-empty line and writing it out in tab-delimited columns. That makes further processing easy. Alternatively, at the third-to-last line of the code above, the values are split into `vallist` in a convenient form for further processing. Note that in `vallist` the values are still strings, so if you were to do computations with them, you would need to convert them into `int` or `float` values first.